# How do I convert a string to a number so I can add another number to it in C#?

Tags: c#, string, int

If I have a string with a value like `"20"`, how can I convert it to an integer so I can add it to another number?

Here's some code that might explain how I want it to be:

```
string myString = "20";
myString = myString + 2;
```

Now the string `myString` should be `"22"`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to convert you string to `int` and then do addition. Later you can convert the resultant `int` to string.

For converting string to integer you can use `Convert.ToInt32`, `int.Parse`, or a safer option [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which would not raise an exception in case of invalid string.

```
int number1;
int number2 = 2;

if(!int.TryParse(myString, out number1)
{
  //invalid string
}
string result = (number1 + number2).ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string myString = "20";
myString = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(myString) + 2);
```

Comment: Glad I could help.  As you can see from the other comments/answers, this can be done in various ways, but the main thing is that you need to make sure both values are integers (or other numerical datatype) before you do arithmetic addition.  If you don't, you'll get string concatination with the plus operator.

Answer (score 3):

You'l need to parse the string to do arithmetic:

```
string myString = "20";
myString = (int.Parse(myString) + 2).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it can be done

```
string myString = "20";
int val = Convert.ToInt32(myString);
myString = (val + 2).ToString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another fun way to do it is:

```
   using System.Data;

   //...

   string myString = "20";
   string addition = "+ 2";

   DataTable dt = new DataTable();

   myString = dt.Compute(myString + addition, string.Empty).ToString();
```

And here is even more fun:

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

//...

string myString = "20";

CodeDomProvider codeProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
ICodeCompiler icc = codeProvider.CreateCompiler();
System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
CompilerResults results = icc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(
    parameters,
    string.Format(@"
namespace N{{
public static class C{{
public static string M(){{
return ({0} + {1}).ToString();
}}}}}}",
        myString,
        "2"));

myString = results
    .CompiledAssembly
    .GetType("N.C")
    .GetMethod("M")
    .Invoke(null, null)
    .ToString();
```

Of course none of this is recommended, unless there is no other way. Posted just as a curiosity :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your actual need, but for the sample code, you might be better with:

```
int myInt = 20;

myInt = myInt + 2;

//To do something:
something.Text = myInt.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string myString = "20";
int num = Convert.ToInt32(myString) + 2;
myString = num.toString();
```